# NSString memory management issue: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: objective-c, foundation

I have an NSString declared like this :

**.h:**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{

        NSString * aString;

}
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *aString;
```

**.m :**

```
@synthesize aString;

......

aString=[[NSString alloc]init];
aString=@"Hello World";

NSLog(@"%@",aString);//The app crashes here
```

The app crashes with this stack trace:

```
-[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

Comment: is the code you posted in the .m File is in the same method?

Comment: No, actually, the allocation of the String is in `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` delegate method, and i try to read it in another method. Is that a problem ?

Comment: I'd say so.  You're only allocating a local copy of aString

Answer (score 8, accepted):

remove the line:

```
aString=[[NSString alloc]init];
```

and set values to the property:

```
self.aString=@"Hello World";
```

Doing: `aString=@"Hello World";` means you are setting value to the instance variable, without using the accessor methods of the property, then you are responsible to the memory management and it's more complicated. Get the value by: `self.aString` also.
P.S. Always work though properties, almost never use the instance variables, (only in the dealloc method release the ivar, otherwise if you are not good at memory management you will always have problems, but properties do everything for you)

Comment: This is absolutely correct but you may consider using @synthesize aString = _aString; and then you may set it like _aString = @"Hello World".

Comment: @graver perfect answer. I also had the same problem. When project was simple setting object in a way aString=@"Hello World" worked pretty well, but soon as added few things in my project , app used to crash, eventually I have to write it in a way self.aString=@"Hello World" . A question appears why does COMPLIER throw an error if we are setting the value without accessors?

Comment: Because you have to take care of the memory management when using ivars (without ARC). So when you set `someString = [[NSString alloc] init]`, and after that you need to set it again, first you have to release it (as `someString` holds a strong pointer to the previous value) and then set it again. Otherwise your previous object is leaked. When you use properties, the synthesized accessors do this for you, but if you provide your own accessors you have to take care of the memory management as well...